# How to Automatically Generate Documentation for ReadMe's from Multiple Repositories

Tags: github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, readme, mkdocs

I want to automatically generate a documentation site that contains the ReadMe's from all the repositories within my project. I am a little new to GitHub, so I'm not sure if my terminology is correct. I provide the link to the GitHub page that has all of the repositories.

https://github.com/casework

I was wondering if there is any way to have a website that automatically generates documentation for all the ReadMe's found in any of the repositories. Ideally, this would be a website that recognizes if the ReadMe's were edited or if a new repository was made, and then automatically update the documentation for the website.

I have been looking at mkdocs and Sphinx, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to automatically generate and update documentation based on the ReadMe's from these repositories. As far as I know, these tools would not automatically update the website.

Comment: I guess that you want something like this ("Triggering a Jenkins build from a push to Github"): https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae

Comment: Or look into Travis CI: https://docs.travis-ci.com/

Comment: Did you find a good solution?